# Problem in solving the long run behavior of a Markov chain. (Exercise 1.3 Georgy F.Lawler )

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Exercise 1.3** *Introduction to Stochastic Processes Georgy.F Lawler* :

Consider a Markov chain with state space {1,2,3} and transition matrix 
$$ P=
\begin{pmatrix}
   .4 & .2 & .4  \\
   .6 & 0 & .4  \\
   .2 & .5 & .3  \\
\end{pmatrix} $$ 
what is the probability in the long run that the chain is in state 1?

**My Answer:** I want to use the invariant probability vector as a left eigenvector. But according to **Perron-Frobenius** Theorem, The matrix P ( Markov matrix) doesn't satisfy the condition to use the invariant probability distribution.( all of entries must be strictly positive, one of them is zero ), so I am thinking to use the square of the matrix P instead of P .

**My question**: How can I use the invariant probability distribution here?

Comment: Suppose that P is a stochastic matrix such that all of the entries are strictly positive. Then the Perron-Frobenius theorem implies that: 1 is a simple eigenvalue for P; the left eigenvector of 1 can be chosen to have all positive entries; and all the other eigenvalues have absolute value strictly less than 1

Comment: Why do you need theorem's conditions to be satisfied? You simply need to find normalized $\pi$ s.t. $\pi P=\pi$ or $\pi(P-I)=0$. That exists even if some entries are zero,and will be unique as long as the chain is irreducible (as in your case).

Comment: @A.S. Just some stochastic  matrices have an invariant probability distribution. and this theorem implies above mentioned conditions to use this $\pi P=\pi$

Comment: ALL (finite) stochastic matrices have an invariant probability distribution. It's unique for irreducible chains. No need for the theorem at all.

Comment: please read page 15 of Introduction to Stochastic Processes Georgy.F Lawler , All stochastic matrices have limiting probability distribution but not invariant probability distribution.

Comment: You got it backwards. All stochastic matrices have an invariant probability distribution but not all of them have a limiting probability distribution (for example if the chain is periodic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the following system of equations will give the left eigenvector (assuming that there is a corresponding eigenvalue: $1$)

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
   P_1& 
   P_2&
   P_3  
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
   P_1&
   P_2&
   P_3  
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   .4 & .2 & .4  \\
   .6 & 0 & .4  \\
   .2 & .5 & .3  \\
\end{pmatrix} .$$

If we want he eigenvector(s) to be long run state probabilites the we have to add the equation that

$$P_1+P_2+P_3=1.$$

So, we have

$$0.4P_1+0.6P_2+0.2P_3=P_1$$
$$0.2P_1+0.5P_3=P_2$$
$$0.4P_1+0.4P_2+0.5P_3=P_3$$
$$P_1+P_2+P_3=1.$$

This system of equations happens to have a unique solution:

$$P=\left(\frac{25}{66} \ \frac{17}{66}\ \frac{4}{11
}\right).$$

The long run probability that the process is in state $1$ is then

$$\frac{25}{66}.$$

The mere existence of this solution shows that there is an eigenvalue: $1$.

Comment: Every stochastic matrix has an eigenvalue equal to 1. No need to assume that - it's simply true.

Comment: @A.S. Right. But I did not want to use a fact that turns out to be true. I could, of course, delete that sentence if you judge that to be an improvement...

Comment: $(P_1, P_2, P_3)$ is a probability vector so the sum of $P_1+P_2+P_3=1$

Comment: @linmu: Yes, and it is.

Comment: Actually we use Perron-Frobenius theorm to solve this problem. $P$ is a stochastic matrix then  Perron-Frobenius theorem implies that 1 is a simple eigenvalue and so on. If the $P$ is not a stochastic matrix with strictly positive entries we couldn't use this method.  But there is another fact here, although the all entries are not strictly positive but for some $n$, $P^n $ has all entries strictly positive so we can use Perron-Frobenius. thank you zoli and A.S.